# Topology checker shows gap which is not marked in red and not identifiable

Tags: qgis, topology

I have a project with more than 100 polygons. I used Topology checker to identify errors like Gaps, Overlaps, Invalid Geometries, and Multi part features and corrected them all.

The process was working fine except for a gap where I am stuck now. Topology checker is listing this gap, but it is not marking it on the map as it did with the other errors.

When I click on the row listing the error, a feature is highlighted in green. However, with this, the QGIS hangs and I cannot do anything else. I cut and pasted the highlighted polygon, after relaunching QGIS. However on running the Topology checker, the error was being listed again, though now, another feature was being highlighted.

Can someone please help? Thanks for reading this. I am using QGIS 3.28[image: my screen after clicking on the row listing the error]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I had not tried it, but did it now. It did not remove the error. v.clean also could not correct the error.